# Issue with response descriptor matching

Tags: restkit

I'm making a request to this url

https://myserver.com/api/users/53a8d8d7e4b06b32f108c4f3/settings

and sometimes this request succeeds, and sometimes it fails. Here is the code I'm using to add the mapping.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseGetDescriptor = 
  [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userSettingsInfoMapping
                                               method:RKRequestMethodGET
                            pathPattern:@"/api/users/:uniqueId/settings"                                                             
                                              keyPath:nil 
                                          statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

When it fails, the HTTP status code is 200, the error code from RestKit is RKMappingErrorNotFound.

I get a helpful debug log from Restkit:

*failed to match: response path **'/api/users/53a8d8d7e4b06b32f108c4f3/settings'** did not match the path pattern **'/api/users/:uniqueId/settings'**.*

Just from looking at this log, the paths seem to match. I believe that is what generates the mapping error. Looking at keypaths of my json response, they are similar to the json returned in success scenario. The response is a 200.

Might anyone have ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post the code for adding the response mappings, and also the code that calls the API that is not working?

Comment: What is the HTTP status code when it fails. Need the mapping code too.

Comment: I've added some code to the post, and the http status code is a 200. The catch is that the request sometimes works, so I'm doubtful that the way that the mappings are added is the culprit.